# How to set up route parameters in Vue.js Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I am attempting to build a basic Vue.js Express profile interface that returns profile info of a specific user based on a route parameter id associated with each user. The `.get()` request in Vue.js is set up as the following:

```
  created () {
    let uri = `http://localhost:3000/users/${this.$route.params.id}`;
    this.axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
      this.profile = response.data;
    });
  },
```

The corresponding `GET` route in Express.js is set up as the following:

```
// mongodb
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = '...'; // connection url
const usersDB = 'users'; // users db name


app.get('/users/:id', function(req, res) {

let id = req.params.id;

  var users;
  const findUsers = function(db, callback) {
    const collection = db.collection('documents');
    // no query filter
    collection.find({}).sort( {username: 1} )
    .toArray(function(err, docs) {
      users = docs;
      callback(docs);
    });
  }
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    // assert.equal(null, err);

    const db = client.db(usersDB);
    findUsers(db, function() {
      // send users
      res.status(200).send(users);
      client.close();
    });
  });
});
```

In the above Express route, I added `let id = req.params.id` with the intention of prompting this route to respond with specific user info based on `req.params.id`. I am not sure how to further configure this route to actually return such info based on id. I tried implementing the following in the route:

`collection.find({_id: mongo.ObjectId(req.params.id)})`

instead of using:

`collection.find({}).sort( {username: 1} )`

...but that did not work. Any idea how to set up this route to return data based on `req.params.id`? Thanks!

UPDATED EXPRESS ROUTE

```
// get all users
app.get('/users/:id', function(req, res) {

  var o_id = new mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id))
  // get all users
  var users;
  const findUsers = function(db, callback) {
    const collection = db.collection('documents');
    // no query filter
    collection.find({'_id': o_id})
    .toArray(function(err, docs) {
      users = docs;
      callback(docs);
    });
  }
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    const db = client.db(usersDB);
    findUsers(db, function() {
      // send users
      res.status(200).send(users);
      client.close();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the results aren't returned because of ObjectId comparision not working. Creating new ObjectID using the id from req.params and then doing collection.find should bring back the results

```
var o_id = new mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id);)
collection.find({'_id': o_id});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. See UPDATED EXPRESS ROUTE in the question above. I attempted to implement what you described, but I am still getting an error with the ```GET``` route in the Vue component

Comment: ```xhr.js?b50d:178 GET http://localhost:3000/users/<<route param id>> 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: Seems Express is not able find the route. Give it a restart, if u haven't, also and a console log req.params.id before the route and inside the route functions.

Comment: It's still not finding the route